# How to inventory apps on Linux Desktop?

Tags: application, audit

[N.B. My first post - guidance welcomed]

We have a small local network of users (5) on deb-based systems and would like to maintain an index of apps installed.

How can we, programmatically, inventory a given Linux desktop installation for all applications added by the user

Optimally, this would include distro repos but, also; appimage, snap & flatpak.  It would exclude more container-ish elements such as docker & lxc/lxd.

Comment: see `etc-keeper` it does more, but dose not easily answer what is installed. If you care about recovering an OS, then you need `etc-keeper`. Or configuration management (such as ansible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). Here's the tutorial to setup it on debian https://tecadmin.net/install-ansible-on-debian-9-stretch/. and you can follow this [one](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/ansible-tutorial-1/#7_Managing_Software_Packages) to manage software package of other hosts.

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation but, learning Ansible not-trivial.  Although it is on my list of to-learn, I am hoping there is another discovery mechanism that is more readily available.

Comment: Thanks to @ebvjr & ctrl-alt-delor, I'm taking the plunge and learning ansible.